# ASP.NET Popup and return value back to parent screen

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Screen and if someone clicks a button to open a popup to select a value, i want the popup to return that value to a specfic text box behind.

How can this be done?  It is on the same domain.  Would ViewState work?

Comment: Do you need to go back to the server to display the popup ? It could be a simple jQuery/CSS client side popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `opener` like this:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('fieldname').value = 'value';
```